# Unused dependencies are automatically removed on save Visual Studio Code Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

How can I disable this feature, without disabling format on save? Is there a way to remove this rule? I could not find it in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Set this in your `settings.json` file to prevent removing unused imports on save:

```json
 "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": false,
  },
```

To open `settings.json` file, press F1, then type "Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)".

P.S. If this didn't work, it might be the ESLint. Check out the `.eslintrc` file; there might be some plugins or rules that remove unused imports. If you hover the cursor over the import statements, there should be the names of the related rules.
*If that is the case, I suggest you disable it per line if necessary rather than disabling it globally*

Comment: How can I disable it by line? Don't think this is eslint because I don't have a .eslintrc file.